# Why am I getting this error? AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'tk'

Tags: python, class, user-interface, tkinter, attributeerror

This code returns the error: "AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'tk'" when ran.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk


def entryField(parent):
    frame = ttk.Frame(master = parent)
    
    return frame

class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
    
        #main setup
        super().__init__()
                
        #widgets
        entryField(App).pack()

        self.mainloop()


App()
```

This only throws an error when the function entryField is called within the App class, when it is called outside of the class App it works fine. I don't see why, as I was under the impression that defining it as class App(tk.Tk) is supposed to give tk attributes to it. Is it not possible to combine class and function based widgets in this way? All examples I have found elsewhere do not involve calling a function-based widget from within a class-based widget.

Traceback since it was requested:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\example.py", line 22, 
in <module> App()
File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\example.py", line 17, 
in __init__entryField(App).pack()
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\[REDACTED]\example.py", line 6, 
in entryField frame = ttk.Frame(master = parent)
                      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 710, 
in __init__Widget.__init__(self, master, "ttk::frame", kw)
File "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\ttk.py", line 527, 
in __init__tkinter.Widget.__init__(self, master, widgetname, kw=kw)
File "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2622, 
in __init__self._setup(master, cnf)
File "C:\ProgramFiles\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.1264.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2591, 
in _setupself.tk = master.tk
                   ^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'tk'
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include the full traceback error.

Comment: I think you might want `entryField(self).pack()`. `App` is a class, not an instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Why am I getting this error? AttributeError: type object 'App' has no attribute 'tk'

You are getting it because of this line:

```
entryField(App).pack()
```

The first positional argument when creating an instance of a widget is taken to be the master or parent of the widget to be created. This argument must be an instance of one of the widget classes or a subclass of one of the widget classes.

In this line of code, you aren't passing an instance of a widget. Instead, you are passing the class. The class isn't a widget, and thus an error is thrown.

In this specific case, the proper way to create your `entryfield` variable is to pass `self` as an argument, since `self` is the instance of the `App` class.

```
entryField(self).pack()
#          ^^^^
```

Comment: Is this because I defined the first argument in 
"def entryField(parent):
    frame = ttk.Frame(master = parent)"
or is this something innate to tkinter widgets that I will need to accommodate for in the future?

Comment: @Nifty_Biscuit: it is something innate to widgets: the master / parent of a widget must be a widget.